# обнаружил скрипт на хосте (PHP) . какую роль он выполняет?

Tags: php

Обнаружил скрипт на хосте.

Я правильно понимаю, что он подключается к сайту (из введенного *get*-запроса) и копирует *html* в файл?

Вот [этот скрипт](http://kupit-koshku.ru/data/parse.txt).

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61113/how-does-heartbleed-exploit-work

Answer (score 2):

Кажется Вы поймали Heartbleed

Посмотрите здесь:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed

Comment: подскажите простым языком: получается , это проблема сервака моего , а не отдельного сайта ?

Comment: Да, проблема сервера. Точнее SSL сервера. Ваш системный администратор сможет решить проблему.

Comment: и еще подскажите : скрипт заливается из-за проблемы SSL и через эту дырку   или просто воруют пароли от сервера и закидывают скрипт ?

Comment: Не возьму на себя смелость на это ответить. Я почитал описание проблемы, но моих мозгов не хватило, чтобы дать Вам однозначный ответ... Лучше все-таки сисадминов спросить, а я программист. Простите...

Comment: благодарю вас.. Хоть буду знать о проблеме такой